# how to convert a json to a php object in symfony2?

Tags: php, json, symfony

Via jquery, I ajax/POST this json

```
{"indices":[1,2,6]}:
```

to a symfony2 action. Right now I only really care for the array, so if this makes things considerably easier I could just post [1,2,6] as well.

**How can I convert this to a php object?**

---

Somehow, this does not work:

```
/**
 * @Route("/admin/page/applySortIndex", name="page_applysortindex")
 * @Method("post")
 * @Template()
 */
public function applySortIndexAction()
{
    $request = $this->getRequest();
    $j = json_decode($request->request->get('json'));
    $indices = $j->indices;
    return array('data'=> $indices);
}
```

gives a

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in .../PageController.php line 64 (500 Internal Server Error)

which would be where I access $j->indices, where $j seems to be null

---

The poster:

```
$.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: "{{ path('page_applysortindex')}}",
      data: $.toJSON({indices: newOrder}),
      success: ...
```

Comment: I guess you didn't use "json" as a name for this POST-parameter

Comment: I am not actively using any name at all, I'll post the js above...

Comment: Ah, so I have to write data: "data=" + $.toJSON({indices: newOrder}) and all is well. Probably there is a nicer solution for this.

Comment: you send a POST request but the JSON you send in the body, have look at my third edit

Comment: +1 for interesting question ... was wondering about that myself earlier that day

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get the data sent via body use:

```
$request = $this->getRequest();
$request->getContent();
```

inspect the output and then act upon. but this will contain the json.

(yep, tested it. this leads to your json)

---

getting a POST-parameter with name json from within a controller:

```
$request = $this->getRequest();
$request->request->get('json');
```

[Request-object](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/controller.html#the-request-object)

---

```
$j = json_decode('{"indices":[1,2,6]}');

var_dump($j);
```

leads to:

```
object(stdClass)#1 (1) {
  ["indices"]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    int(1)
    [1]=>
    int(2)
    [2]=>
    int(6)
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Things can be so easy if you can ask the right guy :)

Comment: Arrgh, but how do I get to the json from the request?

Comment: I cannot seem to get to the json, still. I updated my question to show the actual method in question...

Comment: `$json = json_decode($request->getContent(), true);` - the `true` decodes your json to an array instead of a `stdObj`.